# IBDesignable Build Failed Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an application with many custom views and its working fine with me, but after I upgrade the Xcode to version 9.2 the storyboards can't render the views and always show me Build Failed.
I reinstall Xcode 9.1 and its working fine, the problem just with Xcode 9.2
any help?

[image]

Comment: Did you get any build errors in QTextField?

Comment: What does it say when you click on show?

Comment: @Sweeper - no I can build and run on simulator and device without any problem. the problem in storyboard cant render the views

Comment: @J.Doe - when I click it not show me anything.

Comment: I recommend you file a bug report with Apple, as I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Okay it might be a bug.  I have a large project where it is not working (same Build Failed), but check out this quick example -- https://github.com/drewster99/IBDesignable_Example.git -- works for me.

Comment: @drewster thank you for your support. the example it's working with me, and I check my custom views implementation it's the example but more complex. and still not working in Xcode 9.2 and 9.3 but the older Xcode the views working in storyboards.

Comment: @drewster for this "I recommend you file a bug report with Apple" what your suggestion?

Comment: @drewster I copy the FancyRecordButton.swift and the main storyboard inside my project (very big project) and your example it's not working and I got Build Failed when the Xcode try to render the button. the problem with the project but still I cant catch it and the project working with the old Xcode!!

Comment: The problem with projects contain Watchkit https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/292832#292832